# jQuery clickable not checked input:checkbox? select all check boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Q1:** I create a "jQuery clickable" I want when click on `input:checkbox` in rows checked `it input:checkbox`(like when click on rows)

**Q2:** I want when click on `input:checkbox(no row)` in "first row(tr)" **select all check boxes**?

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/tKBJ2/3/

```
$('.table_show tr, .table_show tr input[type="checkbox"]').live('click',function(){
    checkBox = $(this).find("input").prop('checkbox', true);
    $id = $('input:checkbox:checked').val();
    if (checkBox.prop('checked')) {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', "");
        checkBox.prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        checkBox.prop('checked', true);
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', "#ffd6c1");
    }
});
```

With respect

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to be able to click anywhere in each row, and for that row's respective checkbox to become checked, and you want the checkbox at the top to toggle on/off all the checkboxes below. Correct?

Comment: @Alex It already does the first part - so I'm not sure if that's what the OP means

Comment: Well, it does work if you click the row, but doesn't work if you click the checkbox as jQuery clicks the checkbox again, toggling it back off!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1:

http://jsfiddle.net/tKBJ2/7/

Problem is that when you click the checkbox, it directly sets the checked property, and you directly set it back.

EDIT:

I changed it quite a lot more, but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/tKBJ2/35/

Though to be honest, I'd put the header in a thead, so you don't have to make an exception for the first row.

Comment: Please answer the two questions together. after click on checkbox not add `$(this).css('backgroundColor', "#ffd6c1");` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for this. Edit it for your needs

http://jsfiddle.net/tKBJ2/9/

```
$('table tr input:first').live('click',function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', 'checked'); 
    });
});
```

### UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/tKBJ2/17/

```
$('table tr input:first').live('click',function(){
    $new_value = $(this).prop('checked');
    $("input").not(':first').each(function(a,b){
        if ($new_value == false){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).prop('checked','checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please answer the two questions together

Comment: this is Question & Answer site. You ask one question and I answer one question

Comment: I ask tow question-> **Q1** & **Q2** . You do not see them?

Comment: I do see them. But you should ask one question per post. Create another question (post) to ask your question